Video Player in C# WPF To Play AWS Link
I am using Visual Studio 2022, C#, WPF, NET8.0 to build an application. I want to include a video player which will be able to play videos saved in AWS.
I have coded a player using Media Element, but it is not intuitive and does not offer volume control nor full screen. I am seeking some code for a player which will have everything.
AWS Sample Link: https://englishlanvideos.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Trading+View.mp4

The fact your video is hosted by AWS is irrelevant - the real problem is trying to make a complete player-experience from the half-baked media components in WPF.

The default media element is tricky to get working, and it's fickle even if it does work. I highly suggest sing something like LibVLCSharp.

Do you think developing in UWP will be better for a video player?

Here is a sample for creating a more intuitive video player in WPF with volume control and full screen capabilities. You could refer to it.
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        ...
        x:Name="win" MouseMove="Window_MouseMove"
     Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <MediaElement x:Name="mediaElement" LoadedBehavior="Manual" Width="{Binding ElementName=win,Path=ActualWidth,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                       Height="{Binding ElementName=win,Path=ActualHeight,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                      UnloadedBehavior="Stop" />



        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" x:Name="controlsPanel"    VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Background="#80000000"   >
                <Button Content="Play" Click="PlayButton_Click" Width="75" Margin="5"/>
                <Button Content="Pause" Click="PauseButton_Click" Width="75" Margin="5"/>
                <Button Content="Fullscreen" Click="FullscreenButton_Click" Width="100" Margin="5"/>
                <Slider x:Name="VolumeSlider" Width="150" Margin="5" Minimum="0" Maximum="1" Value="0.5" ValueChanged="VolumeSlider_ValueChanged"/>
            </StackPanel>
        
    </Grid>
</Window>

  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
     
      private string awsVideoUrl = " https://englishlanvideos.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/Trading+View.mp4";
      private WindowState previousWindowState;
      private WindowStyle previousWindowStyle;
      private bool isFullscreen = false;
      private DispatcherTimer hideTimer;

      public MainWindow()
          {
              InitializeComponent();
              DataContext = this;
              mediaElement.Source = new Uri(awsVideoUrl);
              mediaElement.MediaEnded += MediaElement_MediaEnded;
          InitializeHideTimer();
      }
      private void PlayButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          mediaElement.Play();
      }

      private void PauseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          mediaElement.Pause();
      }

      private void FullscreenButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          if (isFullscreen)
          {
              ExitFullscreen();
          }
          else
          {
              EnterFullscreen();
          }
      }

      private void EnterFullscreen()
      {
          previousWindowState = WindowState;
          previousWindowStyle = WindowStyle;
          WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
          WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
          Top = 0;
          Left = 0;
          Width = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenWidth;
          Height = SystemParameters.PrimaryScreenHeight;
          mediaElement.Width = Width;
          mediaElement.Height = Height;
          isFullscreen = true;
      }

      private void ExitFullscreen()
      {
          WindowStyle = previousWindowStyle;
          WindowState = previousWindowState;
          mediaElement.Width = ActualWidth;
          mediaElement.Height = ActualHeight;
          isFullscreen = false;
      }

  


      private void VolumeSlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
      {
          mediaElement.Volume = VolumeSlider.Value;
      }

      private void MediaElement_MediaEnded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
      {
          // Optionally handle media end event
      }
     
      private void InitializeHideTimer()
      {
          hideTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
          hideTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
          hideTimer.Tick += HideTimer_Tick;
      }

      private void Window_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
      {
          controlsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          hideTimer.Stop();
          hideTimer.Start();
      }

      private void HideTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          controlsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
          hideTimer.Stop();
      }

      private void ResetHideTimer()
      {
          controlsPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
          hideTimer.Stop();
          hideTimer.Start();
      }
  }


Thank you, Hui. This solves all my concerns.
